# Enforcing holding limits on ERC721 tokens

Tags: balances, transfer, mint

We would like to enforce a certain limit on total amount of tokens held.
**Note: Tokens issued from our contract. not any erc721 tokens**

Lets say, the absolute amount of tokens held cannot exceed 4.

What is the best way to implement this?

I would propose implementing a require(balanceOf(address)<4) into the following parts of the ERC721 parent contract:

1. into _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId)
2. into _transfer (address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)

is there a better (eg safer or more gas efficient) way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a request in any of the functions that are part of mint.
And for gas efficient, do it in mint's first external function